# What are some ways to use our Angular components in another application's Angular project?

Tags: angular, openshift

There is no code to show for this yet, I just am not familiar enough with Angular to know ways to make this work. Basically there is another team in my company that has an Angular 6 application that hosts widgets, and we will be making an Angular 6 application with several verbose widgets that make sense to appear in the other team's product (their users would want to see our widgets without logging into a separate system if possible).

There is a lot of bureaucracy at play here that makes this challenging, where the other team wants our team as isolated as possible. We have an OpenShift development, test, and production environment, and they have the same. Our widgets are complicated enough to where they would not want to own the development of them.

Ideally, we would be able to deploy our Angular component somehow, and the widgets would be updated in their project without them getting involved, or us having to access any of their code or OpenShift pods (except for once to put the foundational infrastructure in place).  Kind of similar to an iframe html tag, but that is a violation of a security protocol at my company.

Some of the ideas I've had were creating an NPM package of our Angular project that will be in our company's NPM repository that they would include and display the relevant components in their project, however when we deploy new code we would have to recycle their OpenShift Angular pod to have it install the new version of the NPM package, and they (reasonably) do not want to give us access to their OpenShift environment or be involved with our releases.

Another idea was a feature branch off of their angular project that we would host in our development OpenShift environment, but never promote to our test or production OpenShift environment, instead we would merge into their development branch and it would travel up their CI/CD pipeline to go into their OpenShift development/test and then manually pushed to prod. This would require a lot of coordination between our teams, however, due to regular merging of our code and there is fear of our code breaking their CI/CD pipeline, and them not being able to proceed with a promotion to development due to our code not passing tests, etc.

Other than that, are there any Angular features, or OpenShift features where we could inject our component (maybe even as HTML) into their Angular project?  Obviously any solution will require coordination between our teams, but our preferences would be that they:

- Don't require us to have access to each other's OpenShift environments
- Don't require more than monthly or so coordination
- Aren't involved in each other's release cycles
- Aren't affecting the other teams CI/CD pipelines
- Initial infrastructure setup can be large

Comment: Build component library and reuse it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+angular+component+library

Comment: So when we do code changes, they would have to pull a new copy of our library (possibly from our company's NPM repository), correct?  This is an idea I've been fond of however there is hesitance about us recycling their OpenShift pods to pull the new package when we make a code change and deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to rule out npm libs, the alternative would be to provide your widgets in a CDN where the target application fetches your scripts from. Typically such scripts should be versioned, but in your case a "latest" version would probably be less problematic.

Since both projects use Angular, make sure you always use the same version (or at least test thoroughly if they are compatible) before deploying a new version of your scripts.

This could possibly be made a bit more robust by using Web Components (Angular Elements) with Shadow DOM.